# How to detect second enter is being triggered on keyup?

Tags: jquery, enter, keyup

I need to detect the second enter after the first one is pressed. 
Case: I have an input form, first enter is to select a city, second enter is to trigger a submit. Is there any way to do this?

```
$("#this_is_the_input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        This is the first enter to select the city. 
        How do I detect the second enter to submit?
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify second enter?  If they hit enter, leave the field and then later return and hit enter, would that also be considered a second enter, or would that be a new first enter?

Comment: You could see if the city field has a value. If it does then submit the form. `if(e.keyCode == 13 && !{{input class name}}.val())` and `else if(e.keyCode == 13 && {{input class name}}.val())`

Comment: Your select city enter JS code should prevent event from bubbling up to submit trigger. What are you using for city autocomplete/typeahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. The clicks variable keeps track of how many keyup events happened. Hope you have the right keyCode. If its second then it invokes the second alert. Tell me if this is not what you need.

```
var clicks=0;
$("#this_is_the_input").keyup(function(e) {
        console.log("clicks: "+clicks);
    if(e.keyCode == 13 )
            clicks++;
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && clicks == 1) {
      console.log("first click");

    }
  else if(e.keyCode == 13 && clicks == 2){
    console.log("second click");
    }
});
```

Comment: that code will never show "second click" as you are `++clicks` always do odd counts. move ++clicks before if statement, see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9y9v2dh/).

Comment: Personally i'd probably try to use a data element on the Element so it's more self contained.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
count = 0
$("#this_is_the_input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       if(count == 0)
       {
            //This is the first enter to select the city. 
       }else
       {
            //This is the second enter to submit.
       } 
    count++;
    }
});
```